# What format is expected when you are asked to 'present a paper' for an interview (PhD)

Tags: soft-question, advice

I have been asked to present a paper of mine for an interview for graduate school.

There have been previous SE questions regarding 'how to present a paper' etc, however these all tend to focus on what content to include, the speed of presentation, details vs big picture.

I am worried more about the format of my presentation. I have a very short time to prepare, and making a power point presentation would be far too time consuming.

Is it acceptable to have a presentation written on a handwriting software (notability) on my ipad? I would not be writing as I go- everything would be on the presenation already and I would merely talk thorugh/point at various bits of the proof.

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for http://academia.stackexchange.com/ . For what it's worth, you will probably get the best answer if you ask the school/interviewer directly.